# How to queue some part of a program

Tags: java, javafx

I apologize for the topic headline, it might not exactly express my thought but i'll give it a try. If someone knows what's the better headline, please suggest an edit.

So i'd like to create rectangles and give values for them after the button has been pressed. Everything's plain and simple if i know how many rectangles i want to create. Here's where thing gets complicated - i get the rectangle count after i've pressed the button.

I'll explain with an example, so it's a bit more clear:

```
        final ArrayList rectList = new ArrayList();
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(final ActionEvent event) {
                ArrayList getFromMethodAnArrayList = methodWhichReturnsAnArrayList();
                for (int i = 0; i<getFromMethodAnArrayList.size();i++){
                    rectList.add(new Rectangle(0,0,0,30));
                }

            }
        });
        HBox box1 = new HBox(1);
        for (int i = 0; i<rectList.size();i++){
            box1.getChildren().add(rectList.get(i));
        }
```

This code gives an error because when first loaded the rectList is empty. How could i queue adding elements into HBox, so it would be performed after the rectList has been valued.

Comment: You should use threads.

Comment: I don't fully understand use of threads, could you make an example for it?

Comment: Probably something from the java.util.concurrent.Future implementations.

Comment: I don't see how it gives the error you mention, if the list is empty it just won't iterate through it since `size()` will return 0 and `0<0` evaluates to false...

Comment: You will have to populate the `Box` from the `EventHandler`

Comment: @Lucas this is just a sample, my code is longer and more difficult and i can't exactly copy it since the values are defined in Estonian and for non-estonian speaker it will be complete jibberish. 
The error will come along when i try to add HBox inside the VBox and from there to root and so on. The main question right now is how could i queue the HBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Recommendation*

You don't need a queue here and you don't need to multi-thread either, at least as you have currently described your question - additional requirements on the implementation could imply that the use of both of those things are necessary.

*Sample code*

What the sample code does is define a source of items which are model data for something you want to display.  When you click on the create button, it will generate a random number of new items with random data values for each item.  These items will be placed in a queue and a subsequent routine will take the items from the queue, read their data values and create appropriate visual representations (rectangles) for the item data.  It uses a queue data structure, but a simple array or list would have worked just fine.

[image: rectangles]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Random;

// java 8 code
public class RectangleAddition extends Application {
    private final Random random = new Random(42);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        FlowPane   flow       = createItemContainer();
        ScrollPane scroll     = makeContainerScrollable(flow);
        ItemSource itemSource = new ItemSource();

        Button create = createItemControl(flow, scroll, itemSource);
        VBox layout   = createLayout(create, scroll);

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private FlowPane createItemContainer() {
        FlowPane flow = new FlowPane();
        flow.setHgap(5);
        flow.setVgap(5);

        return flow;
    }

    /**
     * The control will
     *   retrieve items from the source,
     *   add them to the scrollable pane,
     *   scroll the pane to the bottom on each addition.
     */
    private Button createItemControl(Pane flow, ScrollPane scroll, ItemSource itemSource) {
        Button create = new Button("Create Rectangles (keep pressing to create more)");

        create.setOnAction(event -> {
            addRectangles(flow, itemSource);
            scroll.setVvalue(scroll.getVmax());
        });

        return create;
    }

    private VBox createLayout(Button create, ScrollPane scroll) {
        VBox layout = new VBox(10, create, scroll);

        layout.setStyle("-fx-padding: 10px;");
        layout.setPrefSize(300, 300);
        VBox.setVgrow(scroll, Priority.ALWAYS);
        create.setMinHeight(Button.USE_PREF_SIZE);

        return layout;
    }

    /**
     * fetches some items from the source,
     * creates rectangle nodes for them
     * adds them to the container.
     */
    private void addRectangles(Pane container, ItemSource itemSource) {
        Queue<Item> items = itemSource.fetchNextItems();
        while (!items.isEmpty()) {
            Item item = items.remove();

            Node rectangle = createRectangle(item);
            container.getChildren().add(rectangle);
        }
    }

    private Rectangle createRectangle(Item item) {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(item.size, item.size, item.color);
        rectangle.setRotate(item.rotation);

        return rectangle;
    }

    private ScrollPane makeContainerScrollable(FlowPane flow) {
        ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane(flow);
        scroll.setFitToWidth(true);
        scroll.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);

        return scroll;
    }

    /** some model data for application items */
    class Item {
        // item will be colored according to rgb values from the (inclusive) range
        // MIN_COLOR_VALUE to MIN_COLOR_VALUE + COLOR_RANGE - 1
        private static final int MIN_COLOR_VALUE = 50;
        private static final int COLOR_RANGE = 201;

        // item will be sized from the (inclusive) range
        // MIN_SIZE to MIN_SIZE + SIZE_RANGE - 1
        private static final int MIN_SIZE = 5;
        private static final int SIZE_RANGE = 21;

        // item will be (z-axis) rotated from the (inclusive) range
        // - ROTATE_SCOPE to + ROTATE_SCOPE
        private static final int ROTATE_SCOPE = 10;

        private Color color;
        private int size;
        private int rotation;

        public Item() {
            color = Color.rgb(
                    createColorComponent(),
                    createColorComponent(),
                    createColorComponent()
            );

            size = random.nextInt(SIZE_RANGE) + MIN_SIZE;

            rotation = random.nextInt(ROTATE_SCOPE * 2 + 1) - ROTATE_SCOPE;
        }

        private int createColorComponent() {
            return random.nextInt(COLOR_RANGE) + MIN_COLOR_VALUE;
        }
    }

    /** a never-ending source of new items fetched in batches */
    class ItemSource {
        // will fetch between 1 and MAX_NUM_ITEMS_PER_FETCH (inclusive) items on each fetch call.
        private static final int MAX_NUM_ITEMS_PER_FETCH = 5;

        public Queue<Item> fetchNextItems() {
            int numItems = random.nextInt(MAX_NUM_ITEMS_PER_FETCH) + 1;

            Queue<Item> queue = new ArrayDeque<>(numItems);
            for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
                queue.add(new Item());
            }

            return queue;
        }
    }
}
```

*Thoughts On Multithreading*

Where you might want a different implementation which does actually use multi-threading is if the item creation or fetching from the item source takes a long time.  For example you need to read the item data from a network, database or very large file.  If you don't multi-thread such things, then you will end up freezing the UI while it waits for the I/O to complete.  A general rule is if the operation you are performing will finish in less than a sixtieth of a millisecond, then you can do it on the JavaFX UI thread without any issue as there will be no visible lag and stuttering in the UI, but if it takes longer than that then you should use concurrency utilities (which are more tricky to use than single-threaded code).

Java has numerous threading mechanisms, which can be used, but you in many cases, using the [JavaFX specific concurrency extensions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm) is the best way to integrate multi-threaded code into your JavaFX application.

The appropriate concurrency utility to use usually would be the JavaFX [Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) or [Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) interfaces if you are doing this on demand from the UI.  You can read the documentation for these facilities which demonstrates sample code for doing things like "a task which returns partial results" (which is a bit similar to your question).

If the thing which provides the items to be consumed is some background long running network task to which items are pushed, rather than pulled on demand, then running it in it's own thread and calling back into the JavaFX to signal a UI update via [platform.runLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) is the way to go.  Another data structure which can aid in such cases is a [BlockingQueue](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5072743) as demonstrated in this [multi-chart creation code](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5072743) - but that is quite a sophisticated solution.

I guess part of my point is that you may not need to use these concurrency utilities for your situation, you need to evaluate it on a case by case basis and use the most appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify your code quite a bit here by getting rid of the ArrayList and populating `box1` when the button event happens:

```
    final HBox box1 = new HBox(1);
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(final ActionEvent event) {
            ArrayList getFromMethodAnArrayList = methodWhichReturnsAnArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i<getFromMethodAnArrayList.size();i++){
                box1.getChildren().add(new Rectangle(0,0,0,30));
            }
        }
    });
```

If it is concurrency that you are interested in, it would be good to read [Concurrency in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm), although I don't think that is the right solution for the question you posted.

Comment: As i mentioned i'd like to give values for them if the button is pressed. The values set the Width and such, which mean that they can't be directly added. Also, this answer fits for my simple example but does not actually answer my question on how to queue a part.

Comment: Thank you, i'm not able to test it right now but will get on it later on at other cpu and then give you back my results